# Reload custom options of associated products in configurable product to display extra/additional attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, javascript, custom-options, associate-products

I'm using Magento 1.9 and trying to do these changes:

- **Create a Configurable Product** and associate 5 products to it
- 4 products have these **custom options**: **color and size**
- 1 product has color, size and fabric

Now, the issue is that if I select options from the dropdown, then **the product which contains the "fabric" option also** that **displays the "color" and "size" options only** somehow **fabric** is not loaded

My first thought was to extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options` and reload from **configurable.js**.

but I'm not sure if this is the right way as I tried to use `getOptions` or `getCustomOptions`, then it returns null.

If someone encountered this also, I would really appreciate the help and guidance.

**UPDATE:**

Here are some step by step screenshots that I hope it will make you understand better what I'm trying to achieve:

- 5 configurable products: http://screencast.com/t/yQlRNRv5
- if I click on Aluminium for example, the product page will display the print size options http://screencast.com/t/sjiSC3Ic2
- now, the Canvas product is the only product that has an extra option that should appear only when you select Canvas: http://screencast.com/t/7hKE0M3gIW2m

The user has the option to change from dropdown from Aluminium to Canvas and that's when the "Canvas Wrap" option should appear: http://screencast.com/t/IMbaebAs4a
and backwards, if you are on Canvas configurable product page, if you select Aluminium, the "canvas wrap" should disappear since the other associated products do not have that custom option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you refering to the dropdowns on the configurable product not getting reloaded? Or some other element which should be refreshed. It would help to have a screenshot outlining what you want to refresh

Comment: I've updated my question. Hopefully, the screenshots will help to better understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without too much trouble, the easiest way was to use this extension: http://goo.gl/a2PSvm

It does exactly what I want.